# Why I'm receiving the message: "Impossible to resolve the host <my_name_account>"?

Tags: command-line

Since a day, each time I open a Terminal session and write any command, I'd been receiving the message:

```
Impossible to resolve the host [my_name_account]
```

[image]

However, the system performs any command I ask for it!

What's wrong, here?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the error as well as the output of `cat /etc/hosts` (*Feel free to clean that output up if there are some custom hosts in there you don't want us to see*)

Comment: I added the image of the error. I saw into the /etc/ directory and I couldn't see any /hosts/ subdirectory. It is a hosts file  which has the following info:127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 jjpg-MS-7788.CASAJJPG

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/etc/hosts` file is misconfigured. The hosts file tells your computer how to resolve certain hosts, such as *localhost* and your computer's host name. Your computer's hostname is set to `jjpg-MS-7788`, but your hosts file lists it as `jjpg-MS-7788.CASAJJPG`. To fix:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

To open your `hosts` file in a text editor. Then, just delete the `.CASAJJPG` from that line so your file should look like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 jjpg-MS-7788
----other lines here, I'm too lazy to copy them for you.
```

Comment: I "catched" your data!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: BTW: Just a curious... How did it happen? I didn't know any about that file and I never touched it. So...

Comment: It could have been when you did the installation. the `.CASAJJPG` seems like it was acting as a domain (your Wi-Fi router, maybe?) so it was added as a host when you first installed the system. However, when you entered your "Computer Name", it wasn't included there.

Comment: So rare!!! Because it works so fine up yesterday. Something changed yesterday, but I don't know what. The only important thing happened yesterday was a power (electricity) cut, because a truck literatelly knocked down a pole. But, as I know, the computer wasn't do something, at this moment. Well, things happen.